# Javascript/node avatar picture in welcome, discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I had someone make me a bot, who doesn't know much. But, I wanted to show their avatar in my welcome.
I'm using the file format that ends with .js node something or other. This is what I got for the welcome.

```
 "embed": {
    "color": 15743107,
    "image": {
      "url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com2.example"
    },
    "description": `**Hewwo ${member.user.tag}!!! So pweased to meet'chu! Teeheehee!! <3**   `,
  }
```

I'm lost, and I don't know where to look, and I have been asking the entire world. Someone mentioned `member.user.avatarURL` When I put it into the code, it just gave a hyperlink to their picture.

Answer (score 1):

1st off, I don't recommend using old-style embeds. Use RichEmbeds, their much better. Since you're using old-style embeds though. I'll show you the code for it.

```
 "embed": {
    "color": 15743107,
    "image": {
      "url": `${member.user.avatarURL}`
    },
    "description": `**Hewwo ${member.user.tag}!!! So pweased to meet'chu! Teeheehee!! <3**   `,
  }
```

The above code should present the users avatar URL!